# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: c#, oracle

Estou com um pequeno problema em minha aplicação. A rotina de **INSERT** me gera o respectivo erro:

> ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Lembrando que o banco é Oracle e a aplicação em C#. Segue código que gera o erro:

```
public void SalvarCampos(ModelCampos model)
{
    connectionBanco.ConectarBanco(modelLogin);

    String query =  "INSERT INTO CARTEIRA_CREDITO (ANOMES, ANOMESBASE1, ANOMESBASE2, ANOMESBASE3, COD_COOP, ATIVO, CENTRALIZACAO, VLR_SUBTOTAL, VLR_CARTEIRACREDITO) " +
                        "VALUES (iANOMES, iANOMESBASE1, iANOMESBASE2, iANOMESBASE3, iCOD_COOP, iATIVO, iCENTRALIZACAO, iVLR_SUBTOTAL, iVLR_CARTEIRACREDITO)";


        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, connectionRateio.connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("iANOMES", Convert.ToInt32(model.anoMes));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("iANOMESBASE1", Convert.ToInt32(model.anoMesBase1));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("iANOMESBASE2",Convert.ToInt32(model.anoMesBase2));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("iANOMESBASE3", Convert.ToInt32(model.anoMesBase3));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("iCODCOOP", model.codCoop);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("iATIVO", model.ativo);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("iCENTRALIZACAO", model.centralizacao);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("iVLRSUBTOTAL", model.vlrSubTotal);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("iVLRCARTEIRACREDITO", model.vlrCarteiraCredito);

    try
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();// <-- ERRO DISPARADO NESSA LINHA!
        command.Transaction.Commit();
        connectionRateio.FecharConexaoBanco();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        //Erro
    }

    connectionBanco.FecharConexaoBanco();
}
```

Segue os tipos do campo na aplicação:

- ANOMES, ANOMESBASE1, ANOMESBASE2, ANOMESBASE3, COD_COOP: NUMBER
- ATIVO, CENTRALIZACAO, VLR_SUBTOTAL, VLR_CARTEIRACREDITO: NUMBER(15,2)

Alguém sabe me explicar o motivo deste erro?

Comment: Atualize sua pergunta com os tipos de cada um dos campos da carteira_credito (campo1,campo2...) e os valores que são passados para iCampo1, iCampo2...o seu erro é provavelmente de tipos incompatíveis de campo/valor

Comment: Nos prepared statements Oracle as variáveis não têm prefixo obrigatório? Vi documentação JDBC que usa `:iCAMPO1` em vez de só `CAMPO1` (na variavel query só, o AddWithValue fica igual).

Comment: Atualizado @Dante!

Comment: @luiscubal, eu também li sobre isso. Já usei os prefixos ':' e '@', porém não adiantou.

Comment: Já respondi aqui abaixo! Confere lá! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que seu erro esteja nos parâmetros passados. Esse erro acontece principalmente quando os parâmetros passados não são iguais aos que estão na consulta e dá pra ver que seus últimos 2 campos estão diferentes dos passados no Value.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("iVLRSUBTOTAL", model.vlrSubTotal);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("iVLRCARTEIRACREDITO", model.vlrCarteiraCredito);


"VALUES (iANOMES, iANOMESBASE1, iANOMESBASE2, iANOMESBASE3, iCOD_COOP, iATIVO, iCENTRALIZACAO, iVLR_SUBTOTAL, iVLR_CARTEIRACREDITO)";
```

Retire os "_" (Underlines) dos parâmetros e teste novamente.

Comment: O command.Parameters.AddWithValue("iCODCOOP", model.codCoop); também!

Comment: Nossa que vacilo! Obrigado Dante! Ponto negativo pra mim.

Comment: Ki nada, cara! Acontece com todos rs Sucesso pra ti!

Answer (score 2):

A primeira coluna representa os nomes no `insert` e a segunda representa os nomes no `command.Parameters` (onde você alimenta cada campo do insert):

```
1) iANOMES ----------------> iANOMES  
2) iANOMESBASE1 -----------> iANOMESBASE1
3) iANOMESBASE2 -----------> iANOMESBASE2
4) iANOMESBASE3 -----------> iANOMESBASE3
5) iCOD_COOP --------------> iCODCOOP
6) iATIVO -----------------> iATIVO
7) iCENTRALIZACAO ---------> iCENTRALIZACAO
8) iVLR_SUBTOTAL ----------> iVLRSUBTOTAL
9) iVLR_CARTEIRACREDITO ---> iVLRCARTEIRACREDITO
```

Não percebeu nada de errado, mais especificamente nas linhas 5, 8 e 9? Os nomes não deveriam ser idênticos? Creio ser este o problema.

Verifique também se não é necessário a adição do `:` em frente a cada parâmetro do `insert`.

Comment: Nossa que vacilo! Obrigado Electus!

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema numa aplicação que fui dar manutenção, entre todos os ajustes para preparar o ambiente, também fiquei quase uma hora batendo cabeça com esse erro **"ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"** até descobrir que a conexão da aplicação estava apontada para uma base desatualizada, e assim, a aplicação passava dois parâmetros a mais para a procedure do banco desatualizado.